# BlackBerry Professional Software - using Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, blackberry

Will the **BlackBerry Professional Software** allow me to get my work email (Exchange Server) and be able to send/receive?  What about contacts and calendar items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blackberry Professional is a small-scale version of Blackberry Enterprise Server (BES). It will sync email, contacts, and calendar entries from Exchange to Blackberry devices. It's limited in its license quantity to 30 handhelds but has almost the same features as BES. Here's a nice feature comparison from RIM: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/services/professional/#tab_tab_compare

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get your work email to work on your BB the BB Professional Software needs to be installed on your works network connecting to the Exchange server as a privileged user as the BB Professional Software accesses the mailboxes on the Exchange Server.  I would ask your Network/System team and see if they can set you up on your BlackBerry.  If not, you can use BB Desktop Manager and use the Redirector.  It connects with your Outlook and syncs your email/contacts/calendar.  But your computer needs to be on connected to Outlook/Exchange for it to work...

Comment: of note: the desktop redirector app will NOT send attachments